# Problem using WP_Query , 'meta_query' in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

so I'm developing a WordPress website, I'm using "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin. I added two fields groups one by the name event_date with a type date and the second one by the name related_service with a type relationship, the related_service it shows in the event type post to relate a service to an event. so in the page single service I want to show the upcoming events that are related to the service. I used WP_Query to show posts from post_type events. i did a piece of code but something is wrong and and don't know what I did wrong.
this code is showing all the events that are coming in the future but not related to the service, so the first array in the meta_query seems to work perfectly buy the second one I don't know what's wrong with it .
the code :

```
<?php
                                $UpcomingRealeatedEvents = new WP_Query(array(
                                    'post_type' => 'event',
                                    'posts_per_page' => 2,
                                    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
                                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                                    'order' => 'ASC',
                                    'meta_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'relation' => 'AND',
                                            'key' => 'event_date',
                                            'compare' => '>=',
                                            'value' => date('Ymd'),
                                            'type' => 'numeric',
                                        ),
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'related_service',
                                            'compare' => 'LIKE',
                                            'value ' => '"'.get_the_ID().'"'
                                        )
                                    )
                                ));
                                while ($UpcomingRealeatedEvents->have_posts()) {
                                    $UpcomingRealeatedEvents->the_post();

                                ?>
                                    <div class="item-download">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                <?php } ?>
```

I tried every thing I can.

Comment: The 'relation' => 'AND' should be just under the meta_query line and not inside the array.

Comment: idk know how did she got there, i put it under meta_query still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem guys and it was so stupid hahahahha this think is just there is a space near to 'value' in the meta_query